# base64 encoding function inserting a newline every 72 characters?

Tags: base64, esp32, arduino-esp32

Hi I was working on base64 encoding audio files (to upload to a server) on an ESP32 and came across this
implementation, [part of espressif's esp idf](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/aaf12390eb14b95589acd98db5c268a2e56bb67e/components/wpa_supplicant/src/wpa2/utils/base64.c#L97):

```
unsigned char * base64_encode(const unsigned char *src, size_t len,
                  size_t *out_len)
{
    unsigned char *out, *pos;
    const unsigned char *end, *in;
    size_t olen;
    int line_len;

    olen = len * 4 / 3 + 4; /* 3-byte blocks to 4-byte */
    olen += olen / 72; /* line feeds */
    olen++; /* nul termination */
    if (olen < len)
        return NULL; /* integer overflow */
    out = os_malloc(olen);
    if (out == NULL)
        return NULL;

    end = src + len;
    in = src;
    pos = out;
    line_len = 0;
    while (end - in >= 3) {
        *pos++ = base64_table[in[0] >> 2];
        *pos++ = base64_table[((in[0] & 0x03) << 4) | (in[1] >> 4)];
        *pos++ = base64_table[((in[1] & 0x0f) << 2) | (in[2] >> 6)];
        *pos++ = base64_table[in[2] & 0x3f];
        in += 3;
        line_len += 4;
        if (line_len >= 72) { // HERE
            *pos++ = '\n';
            line_len = 0;
        }
    }

    if (end - in) {
        *pos++ = base64_table[in[0] >> 2];
        if (end - in == 1) {
            *pos++ = base64_table[(in[0] & 0x03) << 4];
            *pos++ = '=';
        } else {
            *pos++ = base64_table[((in[0] & 0x03) << 4) |
                          (in[1] >> 4)];
            *pos++ = base64_table[(in[1] & 0x0f) << 2];
        }
        *pos++ = '=';
        line_len += 4;
    }

    if (line_len)
        *pos++ = '\n';

    *pos = '\0';
    if (out_len)
        *out_len = pos - out;
    return out;
}
```

I see that there is a variable caled `line_len` which is inserting a newline every 72 characters and also one at the end:

```
if (line_len)
    *pos++ = '\n';
```

Because of this, when I test the function, I always get a newline appended to the encoded strings. When I compare the encoded strings with the `base64` python module (`base64.b64encode(b'blah')`). the python strings DO NOT have any newline appended.

Is there a reason for this decision? I recall 72 characters per line being a constraint of old computer terminals in the early days of email. That have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *requirement* to add newlines to prevent base64 itself from growing very long; but some applications (in particular, email) absolutely require it, so it probably makes sense to include in an implementation.

base64 was originally designed as a content-transfer encoding for email, with the specific requirement that no line must be longer than 72 characters.

Just to spell this out, newlines are *permitted,* and so the implementation you are looking at is conformant with the spec.

If the newlines disturb you, just take them out. A proper test would ignore them when comparing the results from two different base64 encoders anyway; there is no requirement to make lines *exactly* 72 lines long, so some play it safe and make them e.g. 64 characters long max.